# hosting a simple chat on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, comet, chat

use case: 5 - 30 users simultaniously on a chat.

is it a good idea / is it possible to code this on google app engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the Channel API is released, you'll have to use polling to do this. When that API is released, App Engine will be (IMO, caveat that I work on the team) a great tool for this.

Note that with 1.3.6 you can use the Channel API for local development so you can at least get started implementing something, though it won't work in prod.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a stupid question, but couldn't the GAE Application forward incoming messages to all known clients when they are posted to the server?

Why would that not work?

Laures